# Communication relationship when using SimpleBrokerMessageHandler - STOMP Spring

Tags: java, spring, websocket, stomp

Cant seem to find an answer for this question and not enough documentation about [SimpleBrokerMessageHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/broker/SimpleBrokerMessageHandler.html).

I went along this example: https://gerrydevstory.com/2014/03/04/stock-ticker-demo-webapp-using-spring-4-websocket/

and it seems that if the **client** sends a message to the **topic**, all other clients subscribed to that topic will receive that message. As if the default relationship of the topic is `many-to-many`.

I would expect that the relationship would be `one-to-many`, meaning one server to many clients and not many clients to many clients and the server.

This behavior suggests a security/authenticity problem - following the example in the link above, a client could send a fake stock price to everyone else, impersonating to the server.

I would also expect that if this is the behavior, then it could somehow be overridden or changed somewhere in the configuration of spring websockets and stomp but I just can't find enough information on this anywhere.

So the questions are:

1. Is the default behavior really `many-to-many` for the SimpleBrokerMessageHandler?
2. Am I not correctly understanding the meaning of `topic`?
3. Can this behavior be somehow changed or controlled?
4. If not, would ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ or any other third-party broker be of any help for my needs (implementing a `one-to-many` scheme)? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destinations with `/topic` prefix are usually broker destinations, and as you correctly said, anyone can send messages to such destinations and those will be received by all subscribers (messages are actually forwarded to the broker).This will happen with both the simple broker and the broker relay (using any full-blown STOMP broker like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ).

However, [Spring Security 4](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) (in M2 currently), adds websocket security support so you can restrict sending messages or subscribing to destinations (see [JIRA SEC-2713](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2713)). If that's not enough you could implement your own `ChannelInterceptor` and add it to the `clientInboundChannel` so you can process the message and discard it according to your logic.

Comment: thank you very much! I began thinking that I am doing something wrong. As this is going to be used on a production product, I wouldn't want to use a not-yet release version of spring security. Your other proposal for a solution sounds very interesting! Could you provide some information on what I would need to check and do in the ChannelIntercetor code to allow only one-to-many relationship?

Comment: Extend from `ChannelInterceptorAdapter`and implement the `preSend` method with your logic, return null to discard the message. Another option would be creating an app destination (/app/..), let the user send messages to it, process the message in your controller and then send the result to a broker destination for broadcast (see `@SendTo`)

Comment: OK, Thanks. About the other option, that wouldn't solve the authenticity issue. I should have emphasized that in my comment above. Anyway thank you for your help, I will try that.

Comment: sure, this should be used along with websocket security

Comment: I used the `ChannelInterceptorAdapter` suggestion of yours and it worked! I managed to drop out messages that I don't want by overriding the preSend function and returning `null` on dropped messages and `message` when undropped. An important note though: When using XML configuration for websockets, the `websocket:client-inbound-channel` configuration should go after `websocket:simple-broker` and `websocket:stomp-endpoint` (if used)